# ExchangeImpersonation SOAP header must be present for this type of OAuth token

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I have Granted Application Access to exchange online and got an OAuth token.
However when I tried to bind

```
  service.UserAgent = "MyApplication";
        Mailbox m = new Mailbox(email);
        FolderId id = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, m);
        service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", email);
        service.SendClientLatencies = true;
        Folder.Bind(service, id);
```

I get An error reading 
ExchangeImpersonation SOAP header must be present for this type of OAuth token.

but I don't want to use Exchange Impersonate and I cant anyway as this is a service application. It won't have a user who can log in. is their anyway around this beside using Microsoft graph.

Comment: I would suggest you start by reading and see if any of this applies to your issue  https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/issues/212

Comment: Did you try `service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-PreferServerAffinity", "true");` ?

Comment: Seems like all answers to access issues are described here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2015/05/11/best-practices-ews-authentication-and-access-issues/